# What is an ideal way of storing dynamic data in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, model

I have a dynamic form generator where the user can determine the layout of the form and use that form to collect data. The first implementation that comes to mind is a simplistic one:

I have two models, a `Form` model and a `FormRecords` model. The `Form` model stores the `name` and `layout` of the form and the `FormRecords` model stores the `form_id`, `user_id` and the key-value pairs that the layout specifies.

One problem with this implementation would be that the `FormRecords` model would have many entries, where an implementation that used a `FormData` model that stored the entire set of data for a  specific form and specific user combination in an encoded format, like a ruby hash, might also work. But I feel like there are speed issues doing it like this during lookup and data manipulation (i.e. select/join)

Is there a better way to implement this?

Comment: If you only use one table FormData(form_name:string, form_id:string, form_attributes:text,form_fields:text), you can then use either `eval` or `html_safe` to render. Where would the speed issue be?

Comment: @RubyRacer: It's not clear from your comment what form_attributes and form_fields store. Do you mean something like: `formdata.form_attributes = { :male => checkbox, :waist_size => radio_button}` and `formdata.form_fields { :male => true, :waist_size => '32' }`? So I have the layout and the data all in one table, but I still don't have a mapping to a particular user. Note too, that for EVERY user I need to keep the same layout. Updating the layout means updating every user's `form_attributes`.